# Python docstring about the type of object being returned

Tags: python, docstring

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def get_new_foo(self, new_bar):
        return type(self)([self.bar, new_bar]) #How should it be documented?
```

If `get_new_foo` gets called from a derived class, then it would return an instance of the derived class. If multiple classes use `Foo` as base class, then `get_new_foo` will return an instance of the derived class it was called from.

I want to document what type of object `get_new_foo` returns, and I don't understand what/how to document it. I can't say `Returns an instance of Foo` because this will not be the case always.

Comment: I'll note that `Returns a new Foo` is technically accurate, since all subclasses should obey the "is-a" rule; that is, it might not be returning `Foo` exactly, but what it's returning is still a `Foo`.

Comment: @wim: It's building off instance attributes though; a `@classmethod` could be made to work (requiring the caller to explicitly pass the existing `bar` too), but this doesn't seem to be a case where it's an alternate constructor that makes sense to call on the class itself.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  ah, right you are. weird code, hard to offer a less-weird alternative without more context.

Comment: The example example in my question is definitely a `@classmethod` candidate, but my real code is a lot different than the example. I can't `@classmethod` otherwise I would have.

Comment: @wim the question is pretty straight-forward, that is, how would one document the type of object such a method returns. Don't worry about the code, it's just an example and I don't it think needs more context than that.

Comment: What's wrong with `"Returns an instance of type(self)"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide type hints in the docstring.

Since you're writing the documentation on a class that would be the super-class for other classes, it makes sense that you document the base type it returns. Even if the actual type that will be returned once the base class is inherited, the results will still be instances of the base type and at this level, you cannot document anything beyond that anyway.

If you feel sub-classes need more specific documentation for whatever they return, you can simply provide the documentation there.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't be overly concerned about this. Since any subclass "is-a" `Foo` anyway, you're at worst mildly misleading in your chosen wording. If you want to be pedantically correct, you can always expand it to "Returns an instance of Foo (a Foo subclass when called on child class instances)".